# Код не выделяется

Tags: дефект, редактор, блок-кода

Написал [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1093989/32793), выдели свой код и нажал применить форматирование, но код не выделился.

Более того, пропали знаки <>...

Это баг или теперь нужно как-то по новой код форматировать?

Answer (score 1):

Если код внутри списка, то нужно дополнительно 4 пробела ставить.

Comment: Или обратными апострофами или тильдами выделять вместо отступов

Comment: @insolor тогда (нумерованный) список «рвётся»

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, если обернуть в апострофы, потом отступить 4 пробелами, то не рвется. И это проще сделать чем 8-пробельный отступ.

Comment: @insolor «это проще» — да вы их просто готовить не умеете! объясняю на пальцах: вот есть у вас блок кода, уже сдвинутый на четыре пробела вправо. добавляете в начало любой строки этого блока (или даже в пустой строке выше) первым символом что-нибудь отличное от пробела (точку, например), снова выделяете блок (если добавляли символ в пустую строку, то её тоже надо добавить в выделение) и нажимаете `ctrl+k`. этот символ (или добавленную строку) после этого убираете. вуаля! и ни запаха ни шерсти, прошу заметить! (в смысле: никаких лишних тильдо-апострофов).